# Add ID and Type from supplemental tables to parent table using SQL (MySQL & Laravel Polymorphic relations)

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, polymorphic-associations

*Note.* [Also posted on Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/214547/add-id-and-type-from-supplemental-tables-to-parent-table-using-sql-mysql-lara)

I have one table that records all sales and fourteen supplemental tables which contain extra information about a sale. The fourteen supplemental tables are for all intents and purposes the same. They were created long ago when the initial developer thought there would be more differences but actually now that the project has matured they are more similar than they are different. They *are* different however, and as such I need to keep them separate.

#### Current structure

**Sales table**

```
| id      | customer_id | customer_ref                         | ... |
|---------|-------------|--------------------------------------|-----|
| 1237567 | 354         | a6143f8c-b679-47be-9bc0-52457842913c | ... |
| 1237568 | 867         | ref89b72                             | ... |
| ...     | ...         | ...                                  | ... |
```

**Supplemental table 1** Class: *App\SuppOne*

```
| id   | customer_id | customer_ref                         | ... |
|------|-------------|--------------------------------------|-----|
| 2857 | 10372       | 2016-07-01-ab5d09cc37ca              | ... |
| 2858 | 354         | a6143f8c-b679-47be-9bc0-52457842913c | ... |
| ...  | ...         | ...                                  | ... |
```

**Supplemental table 2** Class: *App\SuppTwo*

```
| id    | customer_id | customer_ref | ... |
|-------|-------------|--------------|-----|
| 90488 | 867         | ref89b72     | ... |
| 90489 | 1024        | 0000080992   | ... |
| ...   | ...         | ...          | ... |
```

There are no foreign keys on the tables to join the sales table to the supplemental tables but there is a 'customer_id' and 'customer_reference' which are unique to both the sales tables and also the supplemental tables but they are not consistent. This is what is currently used to join the two as-and-when I need to get more information about a given sale.

I'm using Laravel 5.1 and a MySQL database and I'd like to add two fields to the sales table; supplemental_id and supplemental_type in order to quickly and efficiently create a polymorphic relation.

#### Desired structure

**Sales table**

```
| id      | supplemental_id | supplemental_type | customer_id | customer_ref                         | ... |
|---------|-----------------|-------------------|-------------|--------------------------------------|-----|
| 1237567 | 2858            | App\SuppOne       | 354         | a6143f8c-b679-47be-9bc0-52457842913c | ... |
| 1237568 | 90488           | App\SuppTwo       | 867         | ref89b72                             | ... |
| ...     | ...             | ...               | ...         | ...                                  | ... |
```

I need to add these two fields to each of the sales records but I am unsure how to do this with raw SQL as I expect it would be much quicker than if done in a migration. I'd like to know how (if possible) in SQL, do I deal with the mapping from table_name to App\ClassName. There are about 1.5m records in the sales table and looping over them all will not take an insignificant amount of time.

Comment: It's basically an UPDATE with a Double Joined Select. though honestly why are you doing this when the Select will take care of the visuals?

Comment: I'd like to know how (if possible) it is done using SQL as doing it using PHP in a migration will take too long.

Comment: INSERT INTO Table_New SELECT * FROM Table1,Table2 WHere Table1.key1 = table2.key1 ?

Comment: How do I deal with the mapping from table_name to App\ClassName?

Answer (score 1):

something between the lines of.

It can potentially override the data, for particular sale record (ie. SuppFourteen overrides SuppOne data), but that's how you presented it in your question.

```
$fourteen_tables = [
    'supplemental_table_1' => App\SuppOne::class,
    // ...
];

foreach ($fourteen_tables as $table => $class) {
    DB::table('sales_table')
        ->join($table, function ($join) use ($table) {
            $join->on($table.'.customer_id', '=', 'sales_table.customer_id')
                ->on($table.'.customer_ref', '=', 'sales_table.customer_ref');
        })
        ->update([
            'sales_table.supplemental_id' => DB::raw($table.'.id'),
            'sales_table.supplemental_type' => $class,
        ]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this Jareck, with regards to the joining tables (in rare cases there could be more than one match on customer_id and customer_reference) can this be sorted to take the last record?

Comment: In the update call, I tried `DB::raw("(select max({$table}.id))")` but that doesn't appear to work as expected. On a similar note, I'd like to add a WHERE clause to the join so that only record(s) with a `status` of '1' are matched.